# Translating a question written in a right-to-left language

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

Can someone please tell me what the title of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/138097) means?

> ## ما رايك في موقعنا
>
> ما رايك في موقعنا

Comment: Someone is surely picking on you Josh! You find all the crap nowadays!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I am spam. Please Close/Delete me."

Given, that is a very **rough** translation...

Comment: According to Google Translate it Arabic for: "What do you think about this site??"

Comment: Damnit, beat me to it by a minute

Answer (score 0):

'There is a camel about to spit up on your ankle.'